# How to calculate multiple functions from vector in R

Tags: r, syntax

I want to calculate multiple functions from a vector in an efficient way but I couldn't figure out how.
I tried with pipes but it only works for the first variable, and adding a `,` doesn't work.

```
vec1 %>%
  sd(),
  mean()
```

I guess I could always transform it into a dataframe and use summarize, but I rather not do that.

Thank you,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```r
x <- 1:10

c(sum(x), mean(x), sd(x))
#> [1] 55.00000  5.50000  3.02765

library(magrittr)

x %>% 
  {c(sum(.), mean(.), sd(.))}
#> [1] 55.00000  5.50000  3.02765

x %>% 
  sapply(c(sum, mean, sd), rlang::exec, .)
#> [1] 55.00000  5.50000  3.02765
```

<sup>Created on 2021-11-26 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: You can use `sapply(c(sum, mean, sd), function(f) f(x))` as well

Answer (score 2):

You may try

```
library(dplyr)

x <- c(1:10)

func <- function(x){
  c(mean(x), sd(x))
}
x %>%
  func
[1] 5.50000 3.02765
```

Answer (score 2):

Return the output in a list.

```
calculate_stats <- function(x) {
  list(mean = mean(x), sd = sd(x), sum = sum(x))
}
result <- calculate_stats(1:10)
result

#$mean
#[1] 5.5

#$sd
#[1] 3.02765

#$sum
#[1] 55
```

Separate values can be extracted from the `result` using `$`.

```
result$mean
#[1] 5.5

result$sd
#[1] 3.02765
```